# How to display one item per `type` attribute in a list?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing an Angular 8 application. In one of the views there is the option to display a list of items of class `Product` and this list may be filtered in several ways.

```
export class Product {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public type: number
  ) {
  }
}
```

What I want to do:

Among the attributes of `Product` there is `type`. How can I filter them in order to obtain **exactly one item** per type? What I would do is use this function, but I don't know how to write the logical statement in parentheses.

```
filterItemsOnePerType() {
    this.filteredProducts = Object.assign([], this.products).filter(
      item => (... item.type ...)
    );
  }
```

Notice that it's not really important the item that is going to be selected. What is important is that in the final view I won't see any duplicate among types.

**EXAMPLE**

I have a list of products:

```
[{id: 1, type:1},
 {id: 2, type:1},
 {id: 3, type:1},
 {id: 4, type:2},
 {id: 5, type:2},
 {id: 6, type:3},
 {id: 7, type:2}]
```

What I want to obtain is therefore the following list:

```
[{id: 1, type:1},
 {id: 4, type:2},
 {id: 6, type:3}]
```

Comment: What is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: @goto1 `this.products` is an array of objects of class Product. What I want to obtain is an array (`this.filteredProducts`) of objects of class Product where there is no repetition in `type` attribute.

Comment: I was asking for a sample input and output, something that we can work with and not just rely on your description.

Comment: @goto1 you mean an example so?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: @goto1 example added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 this.filteredProducts = Object.assign([], this.products).filter(
   (types => item =>  !types.has(item.type) && types.add(item.type))(new Set)
 );
```

You might want to use a Set to exclude duplicates.

Comment: Just a curiosity: this would work even if the type was a String and not a number?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Array.reduce` method to filter it out.

```js
const array = [
  { id: 1, type: 1 },
  { id: 2, type: 1 },
  { id: 3, type: 1 },
  { id: 4, type: 2 },
  { id: 5, type: 2 },
  { id: 6, type: 3 },
  { id: 7, type: 2 }
];

const result = array.reduce((result, item) => {
  const isFound = result.find(({ type }) => item.type === type);

  if (isFound) {
    return result;
  }
  return [...result, item];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Going back to your original code, you'd do something like the following:

```js
filterItemsOnePerType() {
  this.filteredProducs = Object.assign([], this.producs).reduce(
    (result, item) => {
      const isFound = result.find(
        ({ type }) => item.type === type
      )
      if (isFound) return result

      return [...result, item]
    }, []
  )
}
```

Hope this helps.